# Jenkins : delete workspace on slave too

Tags: jenkins

I have a job with configuration matrix to perform build on 2 computer (master and slave).
I have "Delete workspace before build starts" option checked on this job.

Unfortunately, workspace is delete only on "master" node, that is node where main job (job which launch all the job necessary to cover configuration matrix) is perform.

Workspace on second node is not delete.

I think it's a Jenkins error : because job has configuration matrix, there is a master job to launch other job. So "Delete workspace before build starts" option is apply only for this master job. I think this option should be apply for all matrix configuration job.

Someone know if I wrong ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After the investigation I found out that Slaves workspaces are not deleted by "Delete workspace before build starts"  method, workspace can be deleted on master only with the method (added by https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Workspace+Cleanup+Plugin).

The best option in this case is to use the script:
https://gist.github.com/rb2k/8372402

Good resource to get additional info regarding Jenkins workspace deletion is:
https://julienprog.wordpress.com/2016/04/14/clean-up-jenkins-workspaces/

Comment: You are welcome. Also good thing to look for some bugs in plugins or features requested to be added to plugins is : https://issues.jenkins-ci.org